# When would two moons line up?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, worldbuilding-resources

I am gearing up for a TTRPG (tabletop roleplaying game) and my world is a similar size to Earth with a smilier number of days. However it has two moons. One is slightly larger than our moon but it orbits every 29.5 days like ours. There is a smaller moon that is closer and it orbits every 25.4 days. Assuming they orbit on a similar plane and the same direction; how long til these two bodies meet up and how long til the next solar/ lunar eclipse?
Ours on average have a solar eclipse every 18 months. I imagine that one or both moons will have their own periods of eclipses but what about one where both of them line up? The supers as they are called.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sort of but I would like to know how long will it take as the post is if it could happen once a year. I know the two moons aligning won't happen once a year but it eventually will. How long is the unknown. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I mostly flagged this question to close as duplicate as the first answer to the question provides you with all the math necessary to calculate everything you're asking about.